# How to return UISearchController under a title on an iPad with iOS 16?

Tags: swift, ipad, styles, uisearchcontroller, ios16

On iPad with iOS 16 searchController displaying on the right side. Like this:
[image: Browser style]

How can I return the searchController's "default" view? Like this:
[image: UISearchController under title]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In iOS 16, there is a new property `preferredSearchBarPlacement` for the `navigationItem`, you can change it to `.stacked` to make it appear like previous iOS:

```swift
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
  navigationItem.preferredSearchBarPlacement = .stacked
}
```